# Why does PyCharm raise a warning when using @property here?

Tags: python, class, properties, pycharm, naming

In tutorials I have seen two types of instance attribute naming for the purpose of using @property. Here is code showing examples of both. They also seem to work differently.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x  # Instance attribute __x defined outside __init__

class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x > 1000:
            self._x = 1000
        else:
            self._x = x

a = A(9999)
print(a.x)  # -> 1000

b = B(9999)  # -> 9999
print(b.x)
b.x = 9999
print(b.x)  # -> 1000
```

I like the behaviour of class A better as it seems that the @x.setter is used immediately in __init__, however that piece of code gives me a warning in PyCharm (I have it as a comment). Why would there be a warning if that is the proper use of a Python's property setter? There are no warnings in class B. Could I somehow call @x.setter in __init__ the same way as in class A without a warning?

Comment: What warning is PyCharm giving? Clearly the code using the setter (and thus taking advantage of the setter) is superior, yes.

Comment: Side note: the setter can be simplified to `self._x = min(x, 1000)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"Instance attribute `__x` defined outside `__init__`"*, per the comment. Which *it is*, OP, but it's just a warning.

Comment: The behavior of `x` is not different. You're observing a difference because in `B.__init__` you're setting `_x` instead of `x`

Comment: An aside: don't use double-underscore name-mangling, e.g. `self.__x` unless you understand what it is and it is a valid use-case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks, I had missed that.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini the behavior does still seem to be different, _x gives the same result, different value is set, but the setter is not used in B.\__init__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25263.

A temporary solution I found was to add self._x = None in the __init__. So the code would be:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = None
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x > 1000:
            self._x = 1000
        else:
            self._x = x


a = A(9999)
print(a.x)  # -> 1000
```

Comment: That's not a great workaround, because the setter could be an expensive operation.