# how to know when i CAN'T use list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

so i'm in the MIT compsci class 6.00.1 and when going through the finger exercises and problems i'm trying to use list comprehension when possible, so far i've been able to.

from the reading that i have done it says that you can always write a `for` loop from comprehension, yet not every `for` loop can be used with comprehension.

i would like to know when i can't and when i can?  do i have to write the loop and then try to put it into comprehension to find out if it will work or not?  is there a way to know before i try to put it into comprehension?

example:

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):

    from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

    letter_list = list(letters)
    for x in lettersGuessed:
        if x in letter_list:
            letter_list.remove(x)
    return ' '.join(letter_list)

print(getAvailableLetters(['a', 'b', 'x', 'z']))
```

comprehension:

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):

    from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

    letter_list = list(letters)
    return ''.join(x for x in lettersGuesseed for x in letter_list if letter_list.remove(x))

print(getAvailableLetters(['a', 'b', 'x', 'z']))
```

now when i try the comprehension it's (my IDE, pycharm) saying that the second x is 'local variable not used' and that lettersGuessed is an 'unresolved reference'.

is this one of the times that i can't use comprehension?  and if so, how can i tell without having to try to write it out?

Comment: Your first example **removes** letters from a list. You are not producing a list at that point, so that loop is not suitable to be turned into a list comprehension.

Comment: Side note: your second version is not a comprehension, that's a generator expression. The same principles apply though.

Comment: @MartjinPeiters there this `if letter_list.remove(x)` in the list comprehension which always returns `None`. the proper list comp would be `letter_list = "".join([x for x in lettersGuessed if x not in letter_list])`.

Comment: Your first example can be converted to one that builds a list, rather than mutates an existing list. Just *filter* as you append elements: `result = []`, then `for letter in letter_list: if letter not in lettersGuessed: result.append(letter)`. Now you have a pattern that can be converted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I was typing out a comment to show how to convert the first loop to something that actually *builds* a list; that example will convert to your list comprehension using the rules in the duplicate, yes.

Comment: how about `def getAvLet(letGues):   return ' '.join(sorted(set(letters)-set(letGues)))` or `def getAvLet2(letGues):  return ' '.join( l for l in letters if l not in letGues)` - and a pycharm warning might also be taken with a pich of salt - sometimes they err: [why-does-pycharm-raise-a-warning-when-using-property-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745248/why-does-pycharm-raise-a-warning-when-using-property-here) - I do not use this IDE but saw several posts with warnings that were off.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: except you got your logic wrong. The original outputs all lower-case ASCII letters that have not yet been guessed. Your version produces all guessed letters that are not lowercase ASCII.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that _a list comprehension should only be used for building list_. Anything else would be considered bad-practice (e.g. using list comprehensions for there side-effects) or impossible to actually do (e.g. trying (re-)assign certain attributes on objects in a list). Also note, if your list comprehension starts becoming unreadable, it would be better to simply use a normal for-loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I trust you. Question is not that passionating so moving on. Thanks for the closure.

Comment: "i'm trying to use list comprehension when possible" that is a bad idea. You should learn to use list-comprehensions *when appropriate*. I.E., when you are building a list with **no side effecs**, and perhaps most importantly, when it maintains/improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

> is this one of the times that i can't use comprehension?

No, you've got several issues in here:

- `lettersGuesseed` has a typo
- your comprehension does not make sense. Why do you use `letter_list.remove(x)` in `if` ?

After all fixes this works as your original code:

```
def getAvailableLetters(letters_guessed):

    from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

    letter_list = list(letters)
    return ' '.join([x for x in letter_list if x not in letters_guessed])

print(getAvailableLetters(['a', 'b', 'x', 'z']))
```

Output:

> c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w y

Comment: This fixes the OP's code, but it doesn't really answer the heart of the question - when can one use a list comprehension instead of a normal for loop?

Comment: @ChristianDean I agree, it answers this specific part "is this one of the times that i can't use comprehension?".  I'll fix the answer

Comment: thank you all for you'll explanations, they are all very helpful. @ChristianDean thank you for pointing out the original question, that has only been half answered.  how to make it work, yes, yet not how am i supposed to know if it will work. probably just more experience and coding.

Comment: Glad I could help spread some knowledge @emetib :-)